# what have to do after user allow all cookies?

Tags: javascript, logic, flowchart

On our website, we are implementing the accept cookies policy.
After the user accept/decline the cookies policy what have to do?
where we have to store the data, what are the data have to store.
we need to use the database or have to store it on local storage

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This is something that you as a developer need to decide. What do you need to do depends on what your app needs to do.

To store the "accept" you would almost certainly have to use local storage - think about what and how would you save it into a database - there is no practical way of identifying individual anonymous users other than using local storage.

Comment: thanks for your answer joel.  but I just want to know how others are doing.
Is there any better approach than ours?

Comment: Well, some websites don't allow a person to login without accepting or they don't show the contents of the website OR they show different advertisement / tracking data when the user has not yet accepted cookies. It really depends on do you need to block/allow something or change ads or something like that :)

The basic idea is that you always block everything that needs cookies until the consent is given, then you can allow using cookies.

 @AjithArasu

Comment: ok thanks for your effort joel